# cursor.moveToFirst() is returning false

Tags: android, sqlite

I have created a database as follows.

```
public class DataBase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private  static  String DB_NAME="MovieData";

    private  static  String TABLE_VARIABLES="data";

    private static int DB_VERSION=1;
    DataBase(Context context)
    {super(context,DB_NAME,null,DB_VERSION);//null is for cursors//sqlite helper classes constructor is being called

    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)  { //Sqlitedatabase class gives us access to database

        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_VARIABLES+"("
                +"_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
                + "Movie_Name TEXT,"
                + "Image_Link TEXT,"
                +"Release_Date TEXT,"

                + "Prediction TEXT);");
        insert_data(db,"Bahubali","https://www.desiretrees.in/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/Baahubali-2-Posters.jpg","2017/06/23","success");
        insert_data(db,"3 Idiots","http://s3.india.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/3-idiots-sequel-1.jpg","2018/06/11","success");
        insert_data(db,"Sagar","http://inthecheesefactory.com/uploads/source/glidepicasso/cover.jpg","2019/07/17" ,"success");

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
    private void insert_data(SQLiteDatabase db,String movie_name,String image_link,String release_date, String prediction){
        ContentValues
                movie_data= new ContentValues();
        movie_data.put("Movie_Name",movie_name);
        movie_data.put("Image_Link",image_link);
        movie_data.put("Release_Date",release_date);
        movie_data.put("Prediction",prediction);
        db.insert("data",null,movie_data);


    }
}
```

the data inserted are just for testing.

i want to access the data base within a fragment. the code for this portion of the fragment is

```
 DataReceiver data= new DataReceiver(getContext());
            movie_name=data.getMovie_name();
            image_url=data.getImagelink();
            release_date=data.getRelease_date();
            prediction=data.getPrediction();
```

DataReceiver is a seperated class for receiving the data from the database. the code for it is.

```
public class DataReceiver {

    private Context mContext;
    private String movie_name,imagelink,release_date,prediction;
    private String[] arrangedstring;

    public DataReceiver(Context context) {
        this.mContext=context;
    }

        public  String[] getMovie_name(){
            SQLiteDatabase db= open();
            Cursor cursor = db.query("data",
                    new String[]{"_id", "Movie_Name"},
                    null,
                    null, null, null, null
            );
            String send[]= arrangeDescending(cursor,1);
            cursor.close();
            return send;
        }
        public String[] getImagelink(){
            SQLiteDatabase db= open();
            Cursor cursor = db.query("data",
                    new String[]{"_id",  "Image_Link"},
                    null,
                    null, null, null, null
            );
            String send[]= arrangeDescending(cursor,1);

            cursor.close();
            return send;
        }
        public  String[] getRelease_date(){

            SQLiteDatabase db= open();
            Cursor cursor = db.query("data",
                    new String[]{"_id","Release_Date"},
                    null,
                    null, null, null, null
            );
            String send[]= arrangeDescending(cursor,1);

            cursor.close();
            return send;
        }
        public String[] getPrediction(){
            SQLiteDatabase db= open();
            Cursor cursor = db.query("data",
                    new String[]{"_id","Prediction"},
                    null,
                    null, null, null, null
            );

            String send[]= arrangeDescending(cursor,1);
            cursor.close();
            return  send;
        }

        private SQLiteDatabase open(){
            SQLiteOpenHelper DataBase = new DataBase(mContext);
            SQLiteDatabase db = DataBase.getReadableDatabase();
            return  db;
        }

        private String[] arrangeDescending(Cursor cursor,int column_no ){
                if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        int count=0;
                    do{
                        arrangedstring[count]=cursor.getString(column_no);
                        arrangedstring=moveStringRight(arrangedstring);
                        count++;

                        cursor.moveToNext();
                    }while(cursor.isAfterLast());
                    arrangedstring=moveStringLeft(arrangedstring);
                }
            return arrangedstring;
        }
```

then cursor.moveToFirst() method returns false. I dont know where i went wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if cursor.moveToFirst() returns false, is because you are not getting results.

You have an error on your insert method, and i believe that your table is empty.

Your table has a column named "Release_Date" but in your insert_data method you are using an incorrect name:

```
  movie_data.put("Release Date",release_date);
```

You are missing a "_"

```
 movie_data.put("Release_Date",release_date);
```

This is probably making your insert queries fail and that's why you are not getting results.

EDIT: Although i don't know what you are trying to achieve with your queries, the .query() method has a param for ordering ASC or DESC your results. So, you could remove your arrange method.

Example for one of your queries with ascendent order by column "Movie_Name":

```
   Cursor cursor = db.query("data",
                    new String[]{"_id", "Movie_Name"},
                    null,
                    null, null, "Movie_Name ASC", null
            );
```

Check the doc: 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html

Comment: Also you will have problems with arrangeDescending method, check that your Cursors will always have 2 columns {_id,x} and when you try to call cursor.getString(2); will fail

Comment: thanks for noticing that.fixing the "_" also didnt help. still returing false

Comment: Take into account that your onCreate method in SqliteOpenHelper will be called only once. So your insert_data are not being re-called. Try to uninstall/launch your app again or use onUpdate method.

Comment: As @miibpa said, reinstall the app. Take in mind that once the cursor.moveToFirst() returns true, your arrange method will probably fail. Order your result set with the param of the query() method.

Comment: you guys mean that i should pass 1 as the column number in each case right?

Comment: @sagar.acharya no, you need to pass the column name as a parameter. Check my answer, i have edited it with an example with one of your queries.

Also, if it helped you accept it as an answer!

Comment: @ale.m this is for getting the query results ordered, but to get the String value you have to call cursor.getString(1) in each case :)